# SQL Server export/import settings: how to

Tags: sql-server

I have sql server 2012 express installed.
Now i must format my pc and then reinstall sql server: there is any way to save the existing configuration of sql server and then reinstall it with a configuration file (or import the configuration file) to restore all settings (users, permission ecc...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you

Installing SQL Server 2012 in unattended mode using command line and configuration file

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ai/archive/2012/05/01/installing-sql-aerver-2012-in-unattended-mode-using-command-line.aspx